# Latest version of Anaconda throwing warning

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I just downloaded Anaconda `4.6.11` macos 64-bit command line installer. The installation was successful. But when I hit `conda create -n py3 python=3` it throws me a **warning** as follows:

`WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.`

And after giving `yes` it throws `md5` sum error.

`MD5MismatchError: Conda detected a mismatch between the expected content and downloaded content
for url 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/conda-4.6.14-py37_0.tar.bz2'`

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I have 4.6.14 and today suddenly I'm also getting the same MD5MismatchError whenever I try to install a new package.

Comment: Yeah, changed laptop...So I'm facing this problem

Comment: Same here. Sounds like somebody's Memorial Day weekend at Anaconda is about to be ruined. Or maybe mine is... Hopefully it's a quick fix!

Comment: It works for me now! Thank you anaconda continuum!

Comment: I can confirm the problem was solved automatically.

Comment: Yes, the anaconda team has fixed it. It's working fine now